# Display the product attribute "color" count for a Woocommerce variable product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, custom-taxonomy

I have some simple products and several Variable products with size and or color variants. On the products that are offered in various colors I would like to show on home page or elsewhere, how many color options exist for said product. So under product image on home page it would show as "Colors: 5" or something similar based on how many variants there are under the color variable for that product.

I have searched and not found much mention of how this is done in WooCommerce.

(Using Divi theme in Wordpress with WooCommerce plugin.)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done building a custom shortcode that will output each product attribute name with the terms count used for variations for a variable product ID:

```
if( ! function_exists('product_attributes_count') ) {
    function product_attributes_count( $atts, $content = null ) {
        // Attributes
        $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
            'id' => '',
        ), $atts, 'attr_count' );

        $product = wc_get_product($atts['id']);

        // Only for variable products
        if( ! $product->is_type('variable')) return '';

        $results = array();
        // Loop through product attributes for variations for this variable product
        foreach( $product->get_variation_attributes() as $taxonomy => $term_slugs ){
            $attr_name = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy )->labels->singular_name; // name
            $count = count($term_slugs); // terms count
            // Formatting
            $results[] = '<span class="'.$taxonomy.'">' . $attr_name . ': ' . $count . '</span>';
        }
        // Output a coma separated string
        return explode(', ', $results)
    }
    add_shortcode("attr_count", "product_attributes_count");
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

> **Usage with the shortcode** *(with an argument **`id`** that is the variable product ID)*:
>
> - On Wordpress page or post editor just use: `[attr_count id='40']`
> - On PHP code use: `echo do_shortcode("[attr_count id='40']");`
> - On PHP inside HTML use: `<?php echo do_shortcode("[attr_count id='40']"); ?>`

If you need to target only colors insert this `IF` statement inside the `foreach` loop:

```
if( $taxonomy == 'pa_color' ){
    // the code
}
```